# Position for sphere Geometry by Three.js

Tags: autodesk, viewer, forge

I am adding custom sphere in the forge viewer as below

```
var sphere_minpt =
    new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(niceRadius, 20),               
        material_green)
```

How to set position for custom sphere geometry

Please suggest some solutions

Answer (score 0):

In three.js when you want to change the position of a 3d object you do this:

```
object.position.set ( x, y, z );
```

If you want to change an individual direction you do this:

```
object.position.x = number
```

However I'm assuming since you're using the forge viewer it's may be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
sphereGeom.translate(5, 0, 0);
```